# Reset systemd from deactivating state

Tags: linux, systemd, alma-linux

I have stopped the D3 dababase via command line instead due to systemd have issues stopping the service.

When this happens, I have to restart the server each time which takes 30 minutes at least due to Linux trying to shutting service before reboot. I have left the default timeout limit to 30 minutes.

Crtl + C was pressed as systemd failed to shutdown the D3 service. How do I reset the systemd service so it's out of the deactivating state?

```
$ systemctl status d3_ait
● d3_ait.service - D3 multivalue database
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/d3_ait.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: deactivating (stop) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-11-08 10:57:00 AEDT; 44s ago
  Process: 3668 ExecStart=/usr/bin/d3 -n pick0 -s -a x (code=exited, status=11)
 Main PID: 3671 (code=exited, status=12); Control PID: 4079 (d3shutdown_cust)
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution that might help you was suggested on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1261571/1071040):

> ```bash
> $ systemctl status d3_ait
> ● d3_ait.service - D3 multivalue database
>    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/d3_ait.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
>    Active: deactivating (stop) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-11-08 10:57:00 > AEDT; 44s ago
>   Process: 3668 ExecStart=/usr/bin/d3 -n pick0 -s -a x (code=exited, status=11)
>  Main PID: 3671 (code=exited, status=12); Control PID: 4079 (d3shutdown_cust)
> ```
>
> I solved the issue by killing the process associated with Main PID:
>
> ```bash
> $ kill -9 3671
> ```

Comment: It'll be a problem if the process is in a zombie. I have just encountered it with MySQL server.